# Replacing values in a dataframe after the minimum value in each column

Tags: r, dataframe, replace

I am trying to replace every value following the minimum value in a dataframe with that minimum value.

For example:
I have a dataframe something like the one below

```
a<-c(1:6)
b<-c(6, 1:5)
c<-c(5:6, 1:4)
d<-c(4:6, 1:3)
e<-c(3:6, 1:2)
f<-c(2:6, 1)

df<- data.frame(a, b, c, d, e, f)

df 

a  b  c  d  e  f
1  2  3  4  5  6
6  1  2  3  4  5
5  6  1  2  3  4
4  5  6  1  2  3  
3  4  5  6  1  2  
2  3  4  5  6  1
```

In this case, I would like to convert every value appearing after the 1 into a 1.

```
df

a  b  c  d  e  f
1  2  3  4  5  6
1  1  2  3  4  5
1  1  1  2  3  4
1  1  1  1  2  3  
1  1  1  1  1  2  
1  1  1  1  1  1
```

I was originally looking to do this by finding the location of the minimum value using `which.min()` and, using indexing, replace everything after with the min value, but I only know how to do this for one column at a time. How would I do this for each column in the dataframe all at once?

I will also need to be able to replace each value before the minimum value with a 1, but I think I can figure it out once know how to do the inverse.

Comment: If you know how to do it for one column, you can use `sapply` function to apply it for other columns as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate(across(everything(), ~ case_when(row_number() > which.min(.x) ~ 
           min(.x), TRUE ~ .x)))
```

-output

```
a b c d e f
1 1 6 5 4 3 2
2 1 1 6 5 4 3
3 1 1 1 6 5 4
4 1 1 1 1 6 5
5 1 1 1 1 1 6
6 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `lapply` could do:

```r
df[] <- lapply(df, \(x) { x[seq_along(x) > which.min(x)] <- min(x); x })


df
#>   a b c d e f
#> 1 1 6 5 4 3 2
#> 2 1 1 6 5 4 3
#> 3 1 1 1 6 5 4
#> 4 1 1 1 1 6 5
#> 5 1 1 1 1 1 6
#> 6 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `max.col` to generate a mask matrix `msk`

```
> p <- max.col(-df, "first")

> msk <- row(df) >= max.col(-df, "first")[col(df)]

> replace(df, msk, t(df[cbind(p, 1:ncol(df))] * t(msk))[msk])
  a b c d e f
1 1 6 5 4 3 2
2 1 1 6 5 4 3
3 1 1 1 6 5 4
4 1 1 1 1 6 5
5 1 1 1 1 1 6
6 1 1 1 1 1 1
```